# $p^{th}$ roots of a field with characteristic $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

This is problem 10.9 from the book "Error-Correcting Codes and Finite Fields by Oliver Pretzel".

The Question:

> Show that in a field of characteristic $p$, any element $\alpha$ has at most one $p$-th root $\beta$ (i.e., an element $\beta\in F$ with $\beta^p = \alpha$). Show further that if $F$ is finite, then every element has exactly one $p$-th root

This my attempt at the second part of the question.
From Fermat's little theorem $\beta^{{p^n}-1} = 1$, where $p^n$ is the size of the field. Now multiplying both sides by $\beta$ we get $\beta^{p^n} = \beta$.
If there is $p$ elements then $n=1$ and we can see this is true for any non-zero element. 
For the general case, take the $p$-th root of both sides $\beta^{p^{n-1}} = \beta^{1/p}$ and we know from the multiplicative properties of a field if $\beta$ is a non zero element of the field then any multiple will be.

The first part of the question I'm not sure where to begin.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may find this helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin-Schreier_theory

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We are looking for a root of $x^p-\alpha$; the formal derivative of this polynomial is zero, which means that $x^p-\alpha$ has repeated roots.

Indeed, if $K$ is an extension of $F$ where the polynomial has a root $\beta$, we have
$$
(x-\beta)^p=x^p-\beta^p=x^p-\alpha
$$
which shows the root is unique.

For a finite field $F$, the map
$$
\alpha\mapsto\alpha^p
$$
is a field homomorphism, so it is injective. Finiteness yields surjectivity.

Comment: Is there a nice example of an infinite field $F$ such that $\alpha\mapsto\alpha^p$ is not surjective?

Comment: @rmdmc89 $F(t)$, the field of rational functions over a finite field $F$ of characteristic $p$. If $p=2$, the element $t$ has no square root, for instance.

Comment: egreg, that's perfect, thank you!

Comment: @rmdmc89 It was the question for getting “cum laude” at my oral exam in first year Algebra course. ;-)

Answer (score 11):

If $a^p = b^p$ then $a^p-b^p = (a-b)^p=0$, and since you are in a field this implies $a=b$.  This shows that for a field of characteristic $p$ the map $a \to a^p$ is always injective, and an injective map from a finite set to itself is automatically bijective.

Comment: haha oops. Thanks, I fixed it.

Comment: I'd write $ (a-b)^p=a^p-b^p=0$ or $0= a^p-b^p = (a-b)^p$ instead.